# Generation of values above diagonal numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

Suppose you have a 10x10 numpy array of intensity values extracted from an image. The exact numbers do not matter right now. I would like to take this matrix, and generate vertices for a graph using only the vertex locations of the upper half of the matrix. More specifically, if our matrix dimensions are defined as (MxN), we could possibly write something like this:

```
for x in range(M1,M2,M3...M10):
    for y in range(N1,N2,N3...N10):
       if (x-y) >=0:
           graph.addVertex(x,y)
```

The graph class definition and addVertex definition are NOT important to me as I already have them written. I am only concerned about a method in which I can only consider vertices which are above the diagonal. Open to any and all suggestions, my suggestion above is merely a starting point that may possibly be helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: SOLUTION

Sorry if my clarity issues were atrocious, as I'm somewhat new to coding in Python, but this is the solution to my issue:

```
g=Graph()
L=4
outerindex=np.arange(L**2*L**2).reshape((L**2,L**2))
outerindex=np.triu(outerindex,k=0)
for i in range(len(outerindex)):
    if outerindex.any()>0:
        g.addVertex(i)
```

In this manner, when adding vertices to our newly formed graph, the only new vertices formed will be those that reside in locations above the main diagonal.

Comment: what do you mean by "I am only concerned about a method in which I can only consider vertices which are above the diagonal" and what is `range(M1,M2,M3...M10)`?

Comment: It's not clear what your exact question is.  Maybe try editing this so you can put a `?` mark somewhere.

Comment: I mean that I only need assistance in creation of this loop to only consider the edges, and I do not need assistance in how to actual generate the vertices once proper consideration of the upper triangle is executed. Range(M1...M10) are the column indexes. Range(N1..N10) are the row indexes.

Comment: @tom10 not sure what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
print a

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i, 4):
        print a[i,j],

# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15]]

# 0 1 2 3 5 6 7 10 11 15
```

That is, the key point here is to make the index of the inner loop dependent on the outer loop.

If you don't want to include the diagonal, use the inner loop with `range(i+1,4)`.

Comment: I do not see how this will help me examine specifically the column and row locations only above the diagonal of my matrix without harding coding exclusion of locations 5,10,15,4,8,9,14,12,13

Comment: It's just not clear what you want.  In your example you used (x-y)>=0, which would imply including the diagonal.  Then in you comment you talk about hard coding exclusions for ...,8,9,14, etc, which my loop doesn't produce.  I'm just going to give up.  But also vote to close this because it's not a clear question, nor are you working to make it clear.

Comment: I have understood now what you have provided me and I will post the solution to my problem in an edit so as to hopefully clarify some issues. Also will upvote and conclude as solution.